# CSS grid container outblown when setting grid-template-row: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr

Tags: html, css, css-grid

So I am trying to wrap my head around css grid. What confuses me is the 'fr' unit on the row as I inspect the grid on the browser, '1fr . 834px'. I set on the main container, 'grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr'.  The grid just overblown. When I tried to put the 'height: 250px' in the header container , the column did change, but the row still hold the value 834px. Thus, there will be a huge white gap to the second row. I want it to be when I put the 'height: 250px' on the main container, the next bottom item will follow and stick to become the next column. How do I fix this ? Please help.

P.S : it has to be done only in grid, no flexbox.

Update : Solution found. Have to put height: 100vh on the container and thats it.

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Holy Grail Mockup</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">Header Logo</div>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li>header link one</li>
          <li>header link two</li>
          <li>header link three</li>
          <li>header link four</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="photo">
        <p>placeholder for image</p>
      </div>
      <div class="side-content">Box 1
      </div>
      <div class="side-content">Box 2
      </div>
      <div class="side-content">Box 3
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li>Latest Articles</li>
        <li>Most Views</li>
        <li>Featured</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

</div>
</body>

</html>



* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  text-align: center;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container div {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  display: grid;
  background-color: #393f4d;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  height: 200px;
}

.logo {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}


.menu ul,
.menu li {
  display: grid;
  white-space: nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  font-size: 16px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-inline: 115px;
}

.sidebar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  background-color: #FF7755;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2/4;
  gap: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar .photo {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.sidebar .side-content {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.nav {
  display: grid;
  background-color: #FF7755;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  height: 2vh;
}

.nav ul,
.nav li {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style: none;
}

.article {
  display: grid;
  background-color: #bccbde;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.article p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}

.article .card {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.card p {
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.card .title {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #393f4d;
}

.footer p {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Problem solved. Put a 'height: 100vh' on the main container and it's done

Comment: You should move your above comment as an answer to your question.